# Query message between two parties but hide message to the user who deleted

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a messaging system, below are my tables.

```
table --users
          |u_id | Name |
          | 01  | Aku  |
          | 02  | Sika |
          | 03  | Admin|

table --messages 
          |m_id | sender_id | Body   | sender_deleted | msgTime |
          | 100 |  01       | hello  |     Yes        | 16:04   |
          | 200 |  02       | Hi     |     no         | 16:08   |


table --recipient
          |m_id | recipient_id | status | recipient_deleted |
          |100  |   02         | read   |  no               |
          |200  |   01         | unread |  no               |
```

**PROBLEM**

I want to query conversation from these tables between only the two parties ( thus `u_id=01 and u_id=02`), again i want to hide messages to sender_id when `sender_deleted=yes` but show the same message to `recipient_id` if `recipient_deleted = no`

**NB-UPDATE**

1. I want user with `u_id=01` to see only message with `m_id=200` when viewed on her page
2. I want user with `u_id=02` to see messages with `m_id=100` and `m_id=200` when viewed on her page

This is what i have tried but  I am stacked as to how to go about it

```
SELECT
      m.sender_id,
      m.Body,
      u.Name,
      u.u_id
FROM 
      messages m
LEFT JOIN
      users u
   ON 
      m.sender_id=u.u_id
LEFT JOIN
      recipient r
   ON
      r.m_id=m.m_id
WHERE
      (m.sender_id=01 OR m.sender_id=02 ) and 
      (r.recipient_id=01 OR r.recipient_id=02)
```

Comment: What should the result set look like

Comment: Please I have updated my question, hope it makes it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution. It works by filtering messages exchanged between users 01 and 02, and displaying only the ones relevant to the logged in user:

```
SELECT m.sender_id, m.recipient_id, m.Body, u_sender.Name as Sender,
       u_recipient.Name as Recipient, sender_deleted, recipient_deleted
FROM messages m
JOIN recipient r ON (m.m_id=r.m_id)
JOIN user u_sender ON (m.sender_id=u_sender.u_id)
JOIN user u_recipient ON (r.recipient_id=u_recipient.u_id)
WHERE 
     m.sender_id IN (01,02) 
 AND 
     r.recipient_id ON (01,02)
 AND
     ((m.sender_id=<id> AND m.sender_deleted='no') 
       OR 
     (r.recipient_id=<id> AND r.recipient_deleted='no'))
```

You should replace `<id>` whith the logged user id (01 or 02)

You can, of course, change the returned fields to display what you need.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yea, thanks @Mariano.. it worked but wouldnt it affect performance when there is a lot of rows?

Comment: Hi @George. I think this query will perform nicely if the correct indexes are in place. For instance, `users.u_id` should be a primary key. `messages` should have `m_id` as PK. For `recipient`, the PK depends on whether you can send a message to multiple recipients. In that case, the PK on recipients should be `(m_id,recipient_id)` You can create indexes on sender_deleted/recipient_deleted to improve search time. Notice that by not using LEFT (OUTER) JOINs, the engine has a lot less to traverse. As always, MySQL `EXPLAIN` can help you a lot with this, you can play and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks @Mariano, I have understood every point stated and i am already using the same process you have mentioned. But from your last point, you mean it is better to prevent using LEFT (OUTER) JOINs? that is in my case above

Comment: Yes, I think it is better to avoid them. OUTER JOINs come in handy but they have at least 2 drawbacks: 1) they are not as efficient as INNER JOINs, because the engine has to bring records that match and also records that do not match, and 2) it is easy to set the conditions in a way that brings more records than you really intend. You have to be very careful when setting the ON/WHERE conditions on OUTER JOINs. Unless it is very obvious (i.e. using a LEFT JOIN to avoid using a NOT IN), I try to use INNERs.

Answer (score 1):

The following query returns the columns posted in the question for the required messages:

```
SELECT
msg_details.sender_id,
msg_details.Body,
u.Name,
u.u_id
FROM users u
INNER JOIN messages msg_details ON u.u_id = msg_details.sender_id
LEFT JOIN messages m ON msg_details.m_id = m.m_id
LEFT JOIN recipient r ON msg_details.m_id = r.m_id
WHERE (m.sender_id = <user_id> AND m.sender_deleted = 'no')
OR (r.recipient_id = <user_id> AND r.recipient_deleted = 'no');
```

Replace `user_id` with the current `user_id`.

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bdf4e/16)</kbd>